# Патч datetime.timedelta.total_seconds

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

Я столкнулся с проблемой при тестировании python модуля.

Мне необходимо изменить задержку TIME_TO_WAIT выполнения функции в тесте.

Примерный код функции:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt

def function_under_test():
    TIME_TO_WAIT = 300
    start_time = dt.now()
    while True:
        if (dt.now() - start_time).total_seconds() > TIME_TO_WAIT:
            break
        time.sleep(1)
```

Я вижу решение в заплате для `datetime.timedelta.total_seconds()`, но не знаю, как правильно это сделать.

Comment: обычно это решают при помощи внедрения зависимости -  DI.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать модуль [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) или готовую библиотеку [freezegun](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/freezegun)